# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php

I edit this code to display a mesaje when select is null and i get this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /nginx/user/reports.php on line 235
```

This is code:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT date, impressions, balance, username FROM reports WHERE username = '$username' and date between '$firstDay' AND '$lastDay'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$date,$impressions,$balance,$username);
       if ($rows > 0){
       while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {   
           $ecpm_t3 = $balance*1000;
       $ecpm3 = $ecpm_t3/$impressions;
    $rate = number_format((float)$ecpm3, 2, '.', '');
     echo"<tr>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$date</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$impressions</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$$rate</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center nowrap>$$balance</td>
        </tr>";
       } else {
        echo"<tr>
            <td colspan=\"4\" class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>Not rows</td>
        </tr>";
    }
        }
```

And line 235 is:

```
   } else {
```

How i can resolve this error ? What is bad ?

Comment: You forgot to close your `if` statement.

Comment: `while` can't have an `else` branch. Count curly braces, indent properly, use IDE.

Comment: Your fixed example is here: http://ideone.com/wjbqCa

Comment: @ Ilia Rostovtsev i put your code and not show messaje

Comment: @user3164987, well see the answer then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example (fixed and formatted):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT date, impressions, balance, username FROM reports WHERE username = '$username' and date between '$firstDay' AND '$lastDay'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $date, $impressions, $balance, $username);
if ($rows > 0)
  {
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
      {
        $ecpm_t3 = $balance * 1000;
        $ecpm3   = $ecpm_t3 / $impressions;
        $rate    = number_format((float)$ecpm3, 2, '.', '');
        echo "<tr>
                <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$date</td>
                <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$impressions</td>
                <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$$rate</td>
                <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center nowrap>$$balance</td>
              </tr>";
      }
   }
   else
     {
       echo "<tr>
               <td colspan=\"4\" class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>Not rows</td>
             </tr>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT date, impressions, balance, username FROM reports WHERE username = '$username' and date between '$firstDay' AND '$lastDay'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$date,$impressions,$balance,$username);
       if ($rows > 0){
       while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {   
           $ecpm_t3 = $balance*1000;
       $ecpm3 = $ecpm_t3/$impressions;
    $rate = number_format((float)$ecpm3, 2, '.', '');
     echo"<tr>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$date</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$impressions</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>$$rate</td>
            <td class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center nowrap>$$balance</td>
        </tr>";
       }} else {
        echo"<tr>
            <td colspan=\"4\" class=\"nn\" style=\"text-align:center;\" align=center>Not rows</td>
        </tr>";
    }


?>
```